# Monotouch: WCF services and Exception handling

Tags: wcf, exception, asynchronous, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm using a WCF service created with Visual Studio.

I'm doing a call such as GetDataAsync(param) for retrieve data. In the GetDataCompleted handler, I'm using the retrieved data.

The service works. Sometimes I can't retrieve data. In this case, an exception occurred like the following:

```
Exception in async operation: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified ContentLength.
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.CheckWriteOverflow (Int64 contentLength, Int64 totalWritten, Int64 size) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:546
```

How is it possible to catch a similar excpetion? The application still working but the exception is printed at console. I think the exception cames from Channel or something else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, have you figured this out? I have an equivalent issue on the mono framework with both HttpWebRequest, WebRequest, and WebClient classes running with mod_mono on Apache.

The issue only occurs when the http request has a body (not if body is empty and contentlength is 0).

The first request after server restart is always successful, but all subsequent requests are unsuccessful and returns the error you describe.

Please help if you have any info :-)

Br. Morten

Comment: What version of MonoTouch is being used ? The above message **"Exception in async operation"** is only found inside the **MOONLIGHT** profile so it should not print anything on the *console*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately these WCF exceptions can't be caught in Monotouch at present. This seems to be a known bug. See [MonoTouch - WCF Services made by Silverlight tool - Can't catch exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800018/monotouch-wcf-services-made-by-silverlight-tool-cant-catch-exceptions)

Comment: Hmm.. I guess this does answer the question, hence the bounty. My actual problem however is the subpart of the OP's problem that states, that this protocol exception occurs randomly. It does so with the WebClient class, and with the (Http)WebRequest classes. So, basically I don't care if I can catch it or not - I don't want it to occur at all. I solved it by writing a simple HTTP Client directly on the top of System.Net.TcpClient. It is not pretty, but it seems to be stable and will work for me until the general bug is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is:

> How is it possible to catch a similar (red: ProtocolViolationException) exception?

In your service application, catch the `ProtocolViolationException` with the following code:

```
catch (ProtocolViolationException ex)
{
  // do something with your exception here
  // for example, throw a FaultException that will be communicated to the client
  throw new FaultException<ProtocolViolationException> 
        (ex, new FaultReason(ex.Message), new FaultCode("Sender")); 
}
```

For this to be send back to the client correctly, you'll need to set up an additional attribute on the operation contract, like:

```
[OperationContract()] 
[FaultContract(typeof(ProtocolViolationException))]
```

And then, on the client side you can anticipate this specific exception and handle it gracefully, like:

```
catch (FaultException<ProtocolViolationException> ex) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("FaultException<>: " + ex.Detail.GetType().Name + " - " + ex.Detail.Message); 
}
```

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

When using WCF its always good to try to get as much visibility as possible. There are two tools that I often use. They are the WCF Trace Viewer and WCF Config Editor

- SvcConfigEditor.exe
- SvcTraceViewer.exe

Depending if you are on a x64 or x84 machine and the version of .Net they should be located either.

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin Check out

Check out http://merbla.blogspot.com/2009/02/wcf-tools.html