# MonoTouch - WCF Services made by Silverlight tool - Can't catch exceptions

Tags: silverlight, wcf, xamarin.ios

Using the Silverlight service generator a service class is created:

```
   slsvcutil.exe http://localhost/zzz/zzzz.svc?wsdl 
    /namespace:"*,General"  /d:z:\desktop /noConfig  /ser:DataContractSerializer
```

This class then is created and the async methods called.

Even with all calls and constructions wrapped in Exception try/catches, we can not catch errors like "System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException"

We have the exact same code running in Silverlight clients, and errors are caught in try/catch blocks.

Question: Is there another place/method I need to use in order to catch WCF errors when consuming in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. The framework team is fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question well... :)

In my opinion, in the handler for the async request, check if the error is null or not.

```
if(e.Error != null)
{
  // insert code here to fix the error
  // in a similar way you do with catch block
}

else
{
  // normal execution
}
```

Hope it helps you!! Best regards.

Comment: The problem we've had is that errors inside the WCF implementation, such as a simple 404, don't bubble but  cause the app to crash. Even a simple 3 line test app. We can't get the program to get to the stage that the app could catch an error. Errors in WCF don't bubble, they crash the app.

Comment: Can you please file a bug at http://monotouch.net/Support so we can track / fix this issue?  Thanks

Comment: Here's the Bugzilla link, I have reposted it: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691138